# Express the statements using quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

The statement :

> Every student in this class has taken exactly two mathematics classes at this school.

My idea of answer :

It should probably be using a bi-conditional but I cant understand how to frame it. Probably something like :

$$∀x∀y( T(x,y) <=> ( M1(y) \lor M2(y) ) )$$

where T(x,y) means X is taking class y, M1(x) means x is first math class, M2(x) means x is second maths class. The domain for x is all studint in this class and for y is maths  classes in this school.

I'm not at all convinced by the answer. Couldn't find anywhere else either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to write it, using the biconditional that you intuitively 'feel' is involved here (I use $M(x)$ for '$x$ is a math course at this school)

$$\forall x (S(x) \to \exists y \exists z (y \not = z \land \forall w ((w = y \lor w = z) \leftrightarrow (M(w) \land T(x,w))))$$

This really is just a condensed version of Pe's second answer:

Going from left to right: if $w$ is either $y$ or $z$, then that will make $z$ (and thus both $y$ and $z$) a math course taken by the student at this school, and hence the student has taken *at least* two math courses at this school.

Going from right to left: if $w$ is a a math course taken by the student at this school, then it has to be either $y$ or $z$, and hence the student has taken *at most* two math courses at this school.

Combined, this gives that the student has taken *exactly* two math courses at this school.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Pe and your answers combined totally cleared my confusion.

Comment: @momo Great! Glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways that it can be written, but the following expresses it as variable which can be used elsewhere:

- Sx = x is a student in this class
- $q_x$ = quantity of math classes taken by x

$\forall x[Sx \to q_x=2] \\$

In response to your comment, the following expresses the same idea as a simple predicate.

- Mx = x has taken two math classes.

$\forall x[Sx \to Mx] \\$

Here's another way to express it:

- Cx = x is a math class
- Txy = x has taken y

$\forall x[Sx \to  \exists yz[Cy \land Cz \land y \neq z \land Txy \land Txz \land \forall w[(Cw \land Txw) \to (w=y \lor w=z)]]] \\$

Notice that the final expression concerning $w$ is a common way to express the idea that there are exactly two and no more. In other words, if there is any such $w$, it must be identical to either $y$ or $z$. Otherwise, there would be more than just two math classes taken by $x$.

Comment: Could you please give another expression which doesn't explicitly use the number of classes?

Comment: @momo. I added two different ways to write it. It really depends on what you're trying to prove. In mathematical contexts, it's often best to use variables.

Comment: You forgot to include $y \not = z$

Comment: @Bram28. Good point. Thanks.

Comment: @PédeLeão Easy mistake! :)

Comment: The third one is really helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let x be the domain of students in this class, y and z be the domain math classes, and the predicate M(x,y) student x taken math class y

$$ \forall x \exists y \exists z ( y \ne z \land \forall w (M(x,w) \leftrightarrow ( w = y \lor w=z))) $$